# Retain input value on option selected in react-select

Tags: react-select

I'm using react-select 2 in my project. Every time a user selects an option, the input value is cleared which causes the option list to change.
Is there any way to retain the input value so the user can select multiple options?
here is what i tried:

```
<Select
    closeMenuOnSelect={false}
    blurInputOnSelect={false}
    isMulti
    loadOptions={this.resultProvider.bind(this)}
    inputValue={this.state.searchKey}
    onInputChange={this.handleInputChanged.bind(this)}
  />
```

```
handleInputChanged(input, reason) {
    if (reason.action === "set-value") {
        return;
    }
    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        searchKey: input
    });
}
```

I have created a demo to demonstrate this issue:
https://codesandbox.io/s/345rp0m041

Note that this issue only happend with Async select.

Thanks for advices!

Answer (score 5):

I think you are pretty close. A quick way (might not be the best way though) to solving this issue would be to add two more checks to the `handleInputChanged` method:

```
handleInputChanged(input, reason) {
    if (reason.action === "set-value" ||
        reason.action === "input-blur" ||
        reason.action === "menu-close") {
          return;
    }
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      searchKey: input
    });
  }
```

Here's a working demo of your code: https://codesandbox.io/s/8n9mx057k0

Hope this helps!

*Side note: in [V1 of react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/releases/tag/v1.3.0) we had the `onSelectResetsInput` prop to retain the value of the input box when the user selects an option. But seems like it's no longer available*

Comment: thanks @Sahan Serasinghe, it still not work with Async select.
When i select one option, the menu list show "no option".

Comment: I think my question is not clear, what i'm trying to archive is the option list still display when user select one option, so he can select some others.

Comment: For anyone that wants to be able to select entries from the options as well, you will need to set a value state and also clear the searchKey state in the onChange handler.